# Maths Trignometric function

Tags: trigonometry

Hello guys this is my first time posting here.I need help to understand the question and the answer I have posted in the images.I need to know what this question is asking and how is the question being solved.I know trignometric functions but do not know how to solve these type of trignometric questions.I will be solving these types of questions in my exams.I am waiting for your answers so I can learn.Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! We'll be glad to help you but you should present the question in  a proper way. You should indeed use MathJax and explain you r work and effort on it.  Refer also to [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Please try to improve that otherwise soon your question will be downvoted, closed and then deleted.

Comment: What is $\phi$ in your image?

Comment: Hello how  should I improve my question?

Comment: @FaisalKhawar Read the link given and this one to format the question properly in MathJax [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @FaisalKhawar Let us know if you are going to improve the question.

Comment: I am new to this website.Just joined.I am not able to understand the MathJax.

Comment: I have just joined here to stay and I know I will improve with time but how can you expect me to learn everything in a day?

Comment: @FaisalKhawar You don't need to. I still rely on the MathJax tutorial from time to time. You just find the symbol you want on the webpage and input it into your question.

Comment: Ok I will try to find.

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this, I like to make a quick substitution: $x = \cos\theta$. Then,

$$2 \cos^2 \theta - \cos\theta = 0 \;\;\; \text{becomes} \;\;\; 2x^2 - x = 0$$

Solve for $x$ in this latter equation to get some solutions.

So say your solutions were hypothetically $x = 1$ and $x=0$ (note: these are hypothetical solutions to an equation, **not** necessarily solutions to the one above). Then, remembering $x = \cos \theta$,

$$x = 1 \;\;\; \text{means} \;\;\; \cos \theta = 1$$
$$x = 0 \;\;\; \text{means} \;\;\; \cos \theta = 0$$

From there, you want to find which $\theta$ in the interval in the problem yield the values you found. (Don't forget that $\cos\theta$ and other related functions are periodic, which may prove helpful sometimes. So if $\cos (\theta) =1$, so does $\cos (\theta + 2\pi)$, for example.)

Plugging in the values for $\theta$ you find into the original equation will also prove helpful to double-check them. (I forget if this method introduces extraneous solutions. I don't think it does but I could be wrong. Regardless, checking solutions like this is always a good paranoia check.)

If none of the values in the given interval yield a solution to the equation, then you say the solution set is $\emptyset$: this means "this solution set is empty," or equivalently "there are no solutions."

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand.If you could solve the problem if posted step by step it would be helpful.

Comment: @FaisalKhawar What in particular don't you understand? We usually discourage line-by-line answers since they don't let the OP think for themselves.